# How to add my own custom button in each blog/post of WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to add my own button in each blog. When will click I separate popup will open and my some calculation will be done here. Similar as Tweet Share is working right know.

Comment: Can you post the PHP that is contained with the post.php loop, please? It's difficult to answer your question without this

Answer (score 0):

You can use fancybox to open popup and display your calculations in that popup.

See demo of fancybox popup [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples)

See sample code below:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline1" title="My Calculations"><input type="button" value="Mybtn"></a>

<div id="inline1" style="width:400px;display: none;">
// your calculations here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Friends for your answer and advise 
I solved this problem and added a my own button in each post. Following is the code.

```
add_action('the_content','customFields');
function customFields($text)
    {
        global $post;
        if($post->post_type=='post')
        {
            return $text."<div style='width:100%;text-align:center'><a href=javascript:(function(){var%20url='".$URL;window.open(url,'Yahoo','width=600,height=500');})();><image src='".$imgURL."'/></a></div>";
        }
    }
```